# expressjs how to render values?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to read some values from `index.jade` inputs and then deal with them.

How should I render them?

indexjade:

```
extends layout

    block content
      h1= title
      p Welcome to #{title}
        br
      label(text='privk')

      input(type="text" value="public key" name="pubkey")

      input(type="text" value="private key" name="privkey")
      br
      button(type="submit" onclick="go()")
```

Comment: So, this is your index.jade and want to read some values from this?
Can u specify what u mean by "values"

Comment: @Ammar i want to read values from the input field

Comment: You will simply do it with javascript

Comment: you need to define a post- action in your index.js in routes folder (or however you defined your route in app.js) and do the code there with stuff like req.body.pubkey...

Comment: @YuriyZhulinskiy check out my below answer, I think might help you.

Answer (score 0):

What I found in your above sample is that you are missing comma `(,)` after each attribute in input, second I found your are missing `#{}` to render the server data attribute values.
You can read more from following links to know more about jade.

https://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs/#basics

http://jade-lang.com/reference

I am hoping you are sending data from express while rendering your jade template.

**I am expecting data looks like this**

`{ 
  title: 'Welcome to Jade', 
  pubKey: 'myPublicKey', 
  privKey: 'myPrivateKey', 
  go: function(){ alert('do something'); }
}`

**index.jade**

```jade
block content
  h1 #{title}
  p Welcome to #{title}
  br
  label(text="privk")

  input(type="text", value="public #{pubKey}", name="pubkey")

  input(type="text", value="private #{privKey}", name="privkey")
  br
  button(onclick="#{ go() }") Go
```